# Count of Subscriptions on Contract

Tags: apex, trigger

There are two object Contract and Subscription.There is Lookup relationship between both. Contract is parent and Subscription is child object.

The child-relationship name between two is: **Subscriptions**

I have written **Trigger** on Subscription object to Count number of subscriptions and display that to Contract. 
Below is my trigger:

```
trigger CountContract on SBQQ__Subscription__c (after INSERT, after UPDATE, 
after DELETE ) {
Set <Id> contractIds = new Set <Id>();
List <Contract> lstContractsToUpdate = new List <Contract>();
if(Trigger.isInsert){
for(SBQQ__Subscription__c s:trigger.new){
    contractIds.add(s.SBQQ__Contract__r.id);
}
}
if(Trigger.isUpdate|| Trigger.isDelete){
for(SBQQ__Subscription__c s:trigger.old){
    contractIds.add(s.SBQQ__Contract__r.id);
 }
}
system.debug(contractIds);
for(Contract con:[SELECT Id,Number_of_Subscriptions__c,(Select Id from 
SBQQ__Subscriptions__r) from Contract where Id IN: contractIds]){
Contract conObj = new Contract ();
conObj.Id = con.Id;
conObj.Number_of_Subscriptions__c = con.SBQQ__Subscriptions__r.size();
lstContractsToUpdate.add(conObj);
}

UPDATE lstContractsToUpdate;
}
```

The code is getting saved without any error.But the field on Contract called: **Number of Subscription** is not getting any updated.

Comment: Have you explored turning the lookup into an M/D and using "Rollup Summaries?  Is that a possiblity?

Comment: Also, there is a logical error. On Update, you're not touching `trigger.new`. If you update the ContractId on a given subcription, then the new contract will not get updated.

Comment: Additionally, this might be better as an aggregate query like [SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM SBQQ__Subscription__c WHERE SBQQ__Contract__c IN :contractIds GROUP BY SBQQ__Contract__c] - this is more row query limits efficient. Also, the building of the contractIds array might be better to use s.SBQQ__Contract__c instead.

Comment: @sebastian I have modified the code .. then also its not working.

Comment: @PhilW  not using the aggregated result can be the root cause of the issue??

Comment: It's incredibly difficult to help you more without some details about your data and what you're doing with it

Comment: I am trying to show Count of Subscriptions related to Contracts.

Comment: The aggregate query likely won't resolve the failure to update but it is a better and more scalable approach.

Comment: Are you getting anything in your contractIds debug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pulling the ids that go into contractIds from a relationship on the trigger.new/old

```
 for(SBQQ__Subscription__c s:trigger.new){
     contractIds.add(s.SBQQ__Contract__r.id);
 }
```

Fields pulled from a parent relationship are not populated in trigger context variables.

So instead do:

```
for(SBQQ__Subscription__c s:trigger.new){
     contractIds.add(s.SBQQ__Contract__c);
 }
```

Comment: Bravo. Good catch!

Comment: @eaeaoo it worked..!! thanks a lot..!!